# Angular Argument of Type Object Is Not Assignable to Parameter Never

Tags: angular, viewchild

I am following along an Angular tutorial that builds a message board using Angular, Node and Express.  My backend is perfectly fine.  It is running fine and returning data at the endpoints I've got so far.  Now on the front end I am getting the error about the message object not being assignable to parameter type 'never'?  What?

```
Error: src/app/app.component.ts:17:33 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
     17     this.messages.messages.push(message);
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MessagesComponent } from './messages.component';
import { NewMessageComponent } from './new-message-componet';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
 //Using the ViewChild decorator to push the data from the parent component
  //to the MessagesComponent message array. 
  @ViewChild(MessagesComponent) messages: MessagesComponent;

  onPosted(message:object) {
    //console.log(message);
    this.messages.messages.push(message);
  }
  
}
```

**messages.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
import { WebService } from './web.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'messages',
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let message of webService.messages">
        <mat-card class="card">
            <mat-card-title>{{message.owner}}</mat-card-title>
            <mat-card-content>{{message.text}}</mat-card-content>
        </mat-card>
    </div>
    `
})
export class MessagesComponent {
  messages: any;
  constructor(private webService: WebService) {
  } 
}
```

**web.service.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class WebService {

  BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:1234/api';

  messages = [] as any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.getMessages();
  }

  async getMessages() {
    var response = await this.http.get(this.BASE_URL + '/messages').toPromise;
    this.messages = JSON.stringify(response);
  
  }

  postMessage(message:object) {
    //return this.http.post(this.BASE_URL + '/messages', message, { responseType: 'text' }).toPromise();
    return this.http.post(this.BASE_URL + '/messages', message).toPromise();
  }

}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<h1>Message Board</h1>
<mat-slider min="1" max="100" step="1" value="1"></mat-slider>
<new-message (onPosted)="onPosted($event)"></new-message>
<messages></messages>
```

If anyone knows what I need to do here I'd appreciate it.
Thanks,
Ironman

Comment: Could you also post the markup in app.component.html? At least the relevant pice for the @ViewChild

Comment: @mrak I just did that.  Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: The messages: any in the MessagesComponent is not initialized?

Comment: @mrak it seems one error begat another.  Please see what the issue is now.  Thanks.

Comment: What about the "toPromise" without braces "()" - is it just a copy & paste error?

Answer (score 0):

in messages.component.ts try this:

```
messages = [];
```

i think you should initialize message so you can push in it.